# How to enable cardboard mode in Youtube Android Player API?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, 360-virtual-reality

I want to enable viewing 360-degree videos from Youtube inside my app in the cardboard mode which splits the video into two halves for the two lenses in a Google cardboard, like in the Youtube app. I'm using Youtube's Player API for Android to show youtube video's in my app but I don't see any option to enable cardboard mode in the YouTubePlayer interface docs.

Please advice how can this be done.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Google VR is now much more easy to use as they provide all the tools you need through the Android SDK.

Seems also that equirectangular format is the most widely accepted format now.

See: https://developers.google.com/vr/android/samples/video360